# Angular - Validation message display after success for two functions

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using two functions in my form submission. If all two functions succeed, I need to show a successful validation message. Currently, it's not working. If the second function fails, the success message is displayed. How do I check this before showing the validation message.

First Function

```js
registerUser(user: cusInfo) {
    let userinfo = { cusInfo: { ...user } }
    this.registrationService.saveUserInfo(userinfo).subscribe(data => {
        },
        error => {
        });
}
```

Second function

```js
registerInfo({ code,name }) {
    let item = { "reserve": { code,name} };
    console.log(item);
    this.registrationService.infoRequest(item).subscribe(data => {

        },
        error => {     
        });
}
```

Form submit

```js
registerCustomer(item, info, reservelockerform: NgForm) {
    this.alertService.clear();
    this.registrationService.checkDuplicateUser(info.userName).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.executionDescription == 'Success') {
            this.registerUser(info);
            this.registerInfo(item);
            this.alertService.success('Registration has been made successfully');
        } else {
            this.alertService.error(data.executionDescription);
        }
    });

}
```

Check form submit function. I need to show my validation message only for both functions are succeeded.

Comment: For `saveUserInfo` and `infoRequest`, what's your API response will be returned indicate that it is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are sending requests and waiting for the responses returned and validating both responses' status together, you may look for [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

Both `registerUser` and `registerInfo` methods are needed to modify to return `Observable`.

```js
registerUser(user: any) {
  let userinfo = { cusInfo: { ...user } };
  return this.registrationService.saveUserInfo(userinfo);
}

registerInfo({ code, name }) {
  let item = { reserve: { code, name } };
  console.log(item);
  return this.registrationService.infoRequest(item);
}

registerCustomer(item, info, reservelockerform: NgForm) {
  this.alertService.clear();
  this.registrationService
    .checkDuplicateUser(info.userName)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      if (data.executionDescription == 'Success') {
        forkJoin([this.registerUser(info), this.registerInfo(item)])
          .subscribe({
            next: (data: any) => {
              if (
                data &&
                data[0] &&
                data[0].status == 'success' &&
                data[1] &&
                data[1].status == 'success'
              )
                this.alertService.success(
                  'Registration has been made successfully'
                );
              else this.alertService.error('Registration is failed');
            },
            error: (err) => {
              console.log(err);
              this.alertService.error('Registration is failed');
            },
          });
      } else {
        this.alertService.error(data.executionDescription);
      }
    });
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-idpxqw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.
Call the functions in order of execution.
Try code below.

First Function :

```
registerUser(user: cusInfo, item) {
let userinfo = { cusInfo: { ...user } }
this.registrationService.saveUserInfo(userinfo).subscribe(data => {
    this.registerInfo(item);
  }, error => { });
}
```

second function :

```
registerInfo({ code,name }) {
let item = { "reserve": { code,name} };
this.registrationService.infoRequest(item).subscribe(data => {
   this.alertService.success('Registration has been made successfully');
  }, error => {  });
}
```

Form submit :

```
registerCustomer(item, info, reservelockerform: NgForm) {
this.alertService.clear();
this.registrationService.checkDuplicateUser(info.userName).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.executionDescription == 'Success') {
        this.registerUser(info, item);
    } else {
        this.alertService.error(data.executionDescription);
    }
});
```

}